# What is the relationship between LevelDB's cache (default 8MB) and Bitcoin's UTXO cache?

Tags: bitcoin-core, leveldb, cache

Please correct me if I am wrong.
Bitcoin uses levelDB to store UTXO set. LevelDB has a default 8MB block cache, and the Bitcoin also has a dbcache(default 450MB).

1. What is the relationship between the two?
2. Which part of the Bitcoin system does the levelDB's block cache correspond to?